# Program a Chant in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning coding using Grok Learning. I am stuck on a problem in the Python Beginners Course "Introduction to Programming 1", which, in one of its modules, asks me to create a program, using the `for x in y` command, that asks the user for a word, and then chants it out letter by letter in this format:

```
Cheer:'code'
Give me a c, c!
Give me a o, o!
Give me a d, d!
Give me a e, e!
What does it spell?
CODE!
```

(Each 'Give me a' is on a new line). Sorry, I am new to this but I'm not sure how to do it, especially with the repeated letters.
Thanks!

Comment: Ok i'm new to this, but how is this too broad? This is a super specific question. Also, this is my first question and i'm already blocked from asking any more! Seriously???

Comment: I also personally do not get how this is a "broad question". But, I think the problem may be that you didn't include your code so far. But, that shouldn't be the issue here, because it says that the question was "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
word = input("Cheer:")
for letter in word:
    print("give me a "+letter+", "+letter+"!")
print("What does it spell?")
print(word.upper()+"!")
```

Comment: How are you helping OP by giving them the answer?

Comment: I thought if he saw the answer he would get a general idea of how the loop works and start using it for future problems , should I delete my answer ? didn't mean to break any rules .

Comment: No, Radwan Diab, that was great, thanks!

Comment: I understand what I needed to do, now that i can analyse the correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help , and thanks for the tip Daniel , will try to hint at the solution first the next time I write an answer.